# Display Format for a .NET Winforms Combobox to Upper Case

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox, formatting

I have an array of objects of type Process
I want to display this list in a combobox, alphabetized and in all caps.

The Process object property "ProcessName" is the 'DisplayMember'; it is a readonly property.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the running processes
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();
        //alphabetize the list.
        var orderedprocs = from p in procs orderby p.ProcessName select p;
        //set the datasource to the alphabetized list
        comboBox1.DataSource = orderedprocs.ToArray<Process>();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ProcessName";

        // Make the display member render as UPPER CASE???
        //comboBox1.FormatString


    }
```

I suspect that the answer lies in the FormatString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could format each item when they're added by subscribing to the `Format` event.

```
comboBox1.Format += (s, e) =>
    { 
         e.Value = e.Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
    };
```

But note that when you do this the first item will be selected so your `SelectedValueChanged` event will fire unless you attach the `Format` event handler before attaching the `SelectedValueChanged` event handler.